# sh: keytool: command not found and JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, bash, android-studio, keytool

I have Android Studio installed on my server and try to generate an APK thanks to it. But I'm not able to generate a keystore as it seems it cannot run keytool.
I've made a small script to check it and it always answers with "sh: keytool: command not found". The script to check if my user is able to run keytool:

```html
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$base_path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
$keystore_path = $base_path."/var/apps/android/keystore/test_keystore.pks";
$keytool_cmd = 'keytool -genkey -noprompt -alias my_alias -dname "CN=My Company, O=My Organization" -keystore '. $keystore_path .' -storepass XXXXXX -keypass XXXXXX -validity 36135';

echo "<b>Executing:</b> $keytool_cmd <br /><br />";
$output = array();
exec($keytool_cmd." 2>&1", $output);
$output = !empty($output[0]) ? $output[0] : "No output";
echo $output; echo "<br /><br /><br />";

echo '<b>Executing:</b> ls -la /etc/alternatives/ | grep   "bin/keytool\|bin/java" <br /><br />';
$output = array();
exec('ls -la /etc/alternatives/ | grep "bin/keytool\|bin/java" 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output); echo "<br /><br /><br />";

die;
```

In addition when I run the script to generate the APK from my browser, my logs return "keytool command not found" but also a problem with JAVA_HOME which is not properly set.
The thing is when I run the same script manually by being connected in SSH with root, I have no problem to run keytool and generate the APK (so the path to Java Home is correctly set). But it seems my user cannot access to java.

My OS is CentOS 6.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks.

Comment: What java are you using? I think only the oracle java has keytool, so, if you are using any of the open jdks, you are out of luck

Comment: Thanks but nope, I use the open JDK on hundreds of other servers and it is working properly. As I said it is working when connecting with root in ssh, but it is not working when using my php script from my browser like if the apache user is not allowed to use keytool. This script is not the problem as it is working well on hundreds of other servers. In addition, when connecting in ssh with the user, there is no problem to run keytool, like when connected with root, (just by launching the script from command), but it is not working directly from the script -> "keytool command not found"... :(

Comment: Try to put the entire path to keytool.